# How do I pass the values to Catboost?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, machine-learning, catboost

I'm trying to work with catboost and I've got a problem that I'm really stuck with right now. I have a dataframe with 28 columns, 2 of them are categorical. When the data is numerical there are some even and some fractional numbers, also some 0.00 values that should represent not an empty values but the actual nulls (like 1-1=0).

I'm trying to run this:

```
train_cl = cb.Pool(data=ret_df.iloc[:580000, :-1], label=ret_df.iloc[:580000, -1], cat_features=cats)
evl_cl = cb.Pool(data=ret_df.iloc[580000:, :-1], label=ret_df.iloc[580000:, -1], cat_features=cats)
```

But I have this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CatBoostError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-112-a515b0ab357b> in <module>
      1 train_cl = cb.Pool(data=ret_df.iloc[:580000, :-1], label=ret_df.iloc[:580000, -1], cat_features=cats)
----> 2 evl_cl = cb.Pool(data=ret_df.iloc[580000:, :-1], label=ret_df.iloc[580000:, -1], cat_features=cats)

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\catboost\core.py in __init__(self, data, label, cat_features, text_features, embedding_features, column_description, pairs, delimiter, has_header, ignore_csv_quoting, weight, group_id, group_weight, subgroup_id, pairs_weight, baseline, feature_names, thread_count, log_cout, log_cerr)
    615                     )
    616 
--> 617                 self._init(data, label, cat_features, text_features, embedding_features, pairs, weight, group_id, group_weight, subgroup_id, pairs_weight, baseline, feature_names, thread_count)
    618         super(Pool, self).__init__()
    619 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\catboost\core.py in _init(self, data, label, cat_features, text_features, embedding_features, pairs, weight, group_id, group_weight, subgroup_id, pairs_weight, baseline, feature_names, thread_count)
   1081         if label is not None:
   1082             self._check_label_type(label)
-> 1083             self._check_label_empty(label)
   1084             label = self._label_if_pandas_to_numpy(label)
   1085             if len(np.shape(label)) == 1:

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\catboost\core.py in _check_label_empty(self, label)
    723         """
    724         if len(label) == 0:
--> 725             raise CatBoostError("Labels variable is empty.")
    726 
    727     def _check_label_shape(self, label, samples_count):

CatBoostError: Labels variable is empty.
```

I've googled this trouble, but found nothing. My hypothesis is that there is a problem with 0.00 values, but I do not know how to solve this because I literally can't replace these values with anything.
Please, help me!

Comment: What the dataset your working with looks like? Can you post a sample of it?